# How do I view and flush the contents of a Linux kernel physical page?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, memory-mapping

I have the following problem with a Linux kernel module (simplified example with no error checking):

```
addr = (uint32_t*) mmap(NULL, 4096, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
   addr[i] = 0xCCCCDDDDD;
munmap(addr, 4096);

addr = (uint32_t*) mmap(NULL, 4096, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    assert(addr[i] == 0xCCCCDDDDD)
munmap(addr, 4096);
```

On certain architectures (Intel x86), this succeeds.  On other architectures (ARM), the code ends up hitting the assertion (though the specific place in the array where it get hits varies).

I have access to the physical pages (`struct page`) of this buffer.  I tried calling `flush_dcache_page` during the close callback of `vm_operations_struct`, however this does not prevent the above code from hitting the assertion.  It's weird since I also make sure to set the `vm_page_prot` to `pgprot_noncached` or `pgprot_writecombine` when creating the mapping.

Three questions:

1) What could be the cause of the behavior that I described?

2) Is there any way I could view actual data in memory in the `struct page`?  I know `kmap` will generate a kernel mapping, but that also may not be written to the physical page and stuck in some sort of cache.  `kmap` when closing the virtual memory area indicates some parts of the memory is filled with zeros.  I tried writing my magic number with `kmap`/`kunmap`:

```
v = kmap(pages[i]);
for (j = 0; j < (PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(uint32_t)); ++j) {
    printk("v[%u] before: 0x%08X ", j, v[j]);
    v[j] = 0xCCCCDDDD;
    printk("v[%u] after: 0x%08X\n", j, v[j]);
}
kunmap(pages[i]);
flush_dcache_page(pages[i]);
```

This is after the user space writes.  Before, the printk statements indicate some portions buffer is filled with my magic number and after it always is, i.e:

```
v[3] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[3] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[4] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[4] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[5] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[5] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[6] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[6] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[7] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[7] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[8] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[8] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[9] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[9] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[10] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[10] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[11] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[11] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[12] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[12] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[13] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[13] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[14] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[14] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[15] before: 0xCCCCDDDD v[15] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[16] before: 0 v[16] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[17] before: 0 v[17] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[18] before: 0 v[18] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[19] before: 0 v[19] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[20] before: 0 v[20] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[21] before: 0 v[21] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[22] before: 0 v[22] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[23] before: 0 v[23] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[24] before: 0 v[24] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[25] before: 0 v[25] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[26] before: 0 v[26] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[27] before: 0 v[27] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[28] before: 0 v[28] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[29] before: 0 v[29] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[30] before: 0 v[30] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[31] before: 0 v[31] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[32] before: 0 v[32] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[33] before: 0 v[33] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[34] before: 0 v[34] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[35] before: 0 v[35] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[36] before: 0 v[36] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
v[37] before: 0 v[37] after: 0xCCCCDDDD
```

However, even after these additional writes, user space still hits the assertions indicating the writes weren't flush to the physical memory.  That's why I would like to examine physical memory directly.

3) Is there any reliable way flush or invalidate all caches in Linux kernel given a `struct page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, there was some caching issues going on.  It turns out the contents of page were still in cache from prior use.  There was a race between the pending writes and the userspace writes.  The solution was to flush the cache when the kernel module was fetching pages.

In my particular instance, it looks like flush_dcache_page is a no-op.  What helped on ARM was using the DMA API -- i.e, dma_sync_sg_for_device.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like undefined behaviour: you are mapping 1024 bytes

```
addr = (uint32_t*) mmap(NULL, 1024, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

and then accesing 4096 bytes in the loop.

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    assert(addr[i] == 0xCCCCDDDDD)
```

So the length in your case is incorrect, from mmap man:

> The contents
>   of a file mapping (as opposed to an anonymous mapping; see
>   MAP_ANONYMOUS below), are initialized using length bytes starting at
>   offset offset in the file (or other object) referred to by the file
>   descriptor fd.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  That was an error in my simplified example -- the original code does not have this issue.

Comment: Could you provide a full sources of simplified example? Could i reproduce this issue on arm qemu?

Comment: I'm testing an actual ARM device with a slightly outdated kernel.  Let try to reproduce in qemu with an up-to-date kernel ... I'll let you know how it turns out :-)

Comment: Is this a special kind of file or just an ordinary one?

Comment: Ordinary.  This problem as been solved, turns out there was a race between cache eviction and the writes the user space program was doing.  Flushing when the physical pages are retrieved from the kernel fixes this.  This is not apparent on Intel due different caching mechanisms